Status on the Tagged PDF project, Part II
This is a follow-up question to Status on the Tagged PDF project.
I'm finding it a bit difficult to figure out what the progress is on the Tagged PDF project; I (think I) know it is in Phase III but what's the status on the progress of this phase?
P.S. Thanks to the involved developers for taking on this huge and very important task.

see the recent news section at https://www.latex-project.org  in particular the DEIMS conference paper and the example collection of UA-2 examples

@DavidCarlisle Thanks for pointing to the mentioned articles. Is math tagging in phase IV or am I missing something?

we have some math tagging in the current phase-III see the examples including real arxiv papers that are at https://github.com/latex3/tagging-project/discussions/72  but it's still work in progress. Those examples (mostly) can be done with a current texlive 2024 lualatex-dev

See the recent news section at latex-project.org and in particular the DEIMS conference paper and the example collection of UA-2 examples.
We have some math tagging in the current phase-III; see the examples including real arXiv papers that are at example collection of UA-2 examples but it's still work in progress. Those examples (mostly) can be done with a current TeX Live 2024 lualatex-dev.
